# How to refresh DOM to accept new click class

Tags: jquery

I have a button with class `DoFirst`

```
<button class="DoFirst">Click First</button>
```

When clicked it does something and I then change it's class to `DoSecond`

```
$(".DoFirst").click(function() {
    // do something
    $(this).removeClass('DoFirst').addClass('DoSecond').html('Click Second');
});
```

Now, I have changed the class and I want to perform a different function now with the same button, then change it all back again

```
$(".DoSecond").click(function() {
    // do something
    $(this).removeClass('DoSecond').addClass('DoFirst').html('Click First');
});
```

The problem is it doesn't seem to recognise the new class after the first click, and just keeps acting as if class `DoFirst` is still active, like the DOM needs refreshing somehow. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to react to DOM changes after page load.

```
$(document).on('click', '.DoFirst', function() {
});
```

same for `DoSecond`.

it's better to use the nearest parent instead of `document`, but as I don't know your structure...

Comment: @DarrenSweeney ya, just a typo, fixed! ;)